# jQuery can't find element in ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am making a ASP.NET 3 MVC project, but it seems i can't make jQuery work properly.

In the view i have something like this:

```
<a id="login">lala</a>
```

Then in the .js file:

```
$("#login").click(function () {
    alert("lal");
});
```

The alert doesn't show on the screen. I've added the reference of my custom .js file in _Layout and updated to the newest library, but whatever I do I can't find any element. What am I doing wrong here :s

Comment: Is this wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` handler? If not, then your event won't work because it's trying to bind it before the DOM finished loading.

Comment: Assuming this is in the ready handler, this code works for me in jsfiddle using chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/4UkAg/.  You may want to add the `href="#"` attribute, otherwise the link won't appear clickable.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function () {
        alert("lal");
    });
});
```

If this does solve your issue, google search for `jquery document ready` and read up on the tons of material already written out there on what this does and why it exists.

Comment: I've tried wrapping it in .ready, but it didn't work. 
Is it possible that there's something specific about ASP.NET MVC 3 that I didn't notice?

Comment: It's **very** unlikely. I work exclusively with MVC3 and I have never run into something like this. Paste your exact code into a JSFiddle and let us check it out.

Comment: That jsfiddle will never work 'cause you're referencing mootools. you need to reference jquery, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/C5rS9/7/

Comment: considering that it works in jsfiddle when you reference jquery correctly, is there any chance you're loading the login panel asynchronously, *after* the $(document).ready() function runs?

Comment: I don't know. How can i check how the page is loaded.

Comment: I rewrote my .js file and everything is working now, still can't find my mistake thou. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Has this been resolved? I am running into the same problem right now